# mockito.veify() is giving wrong invocation count

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am trying mockito.verify() feature, the method invocation is only once but verify is showing invocation 3 times. The unit test has only one test, to ensure no other way this test get affected. 
Mockito.verify(utilClass, Mockito.times(1)).hello(); /// but invocation is 3 times, is the error

I have tried using log, which is showing invocation is once. Added deliberate calling method utilClass.hello() more than once, then showing correct no of invocations.but in the given code where it is called once, is showing as called 3 times.

Class to be tested:

```java
@Component
public class UtilClass {

    private static final Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(UtilClass.class);

    public String hello() {
        logger.info("hello method invoked");
        return "Hello World,"+ hi();
    }

    private String hi() {
        logger.info("hi method invoked");
        return "Hi All";
    }
}
@Component
public class ClassWithDependency {

    @Autowired
    private UtilClass utilClass;

    public String welcome() {
        String msg = utilClass.hello();
        return msg;
    }

}
```

Test case

```
@InjectMocks
private ClassWithDependency classWithDependency;

@Mock
private UtilClass utilClass;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.when(utilClass,"hi").thenReturn("Hi Java");
        PowerMockito.when(utilClass.hello()).thenCallRealMethod();
    }


    @Test
    public void testMock() throws Exception {
        final String msg = classWithDependency.welcome();

        final String msgExpected = "Hello World,Hi Java";
        logger.info("welcome method called:{}",msg);

        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(utilClass, Mockito.times(1)).invoke("hi");
        Mockito.verify(utilClass, Mockito.times(1)).hello();

        Assert.assertTrue(msg.equals(msgExpected));
    }
```

I am expecting the mockito.verify to be successful, but getting error

> org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
>   utilClass.hello();
>   Wanted 1 time:
>   -> at com.sd.demo.powermock.test.injectmock.InjectMockTest.testMock(InjectMockTest.java:54)
>   But was 3 times:
>   -> at com.sd.demo.powermock.injectmock.ClassWithDependency.welcome(ClassWithDependency.java:13)
>   -> at com.sd.demo.powermock.injectmock.ClassWithDependency.welcome(ClassWithDependency.java:13)
>   -> at com.sd.demo.powermock.injectmock.ClassWithDependency.welcome(ClassWithDependency.java:13)
>       at com.sd.demo.powermock.test.injectmock.InjectMockTest.testMock(InjectMockTest.java:54)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
>   .............

Comment: Possibly related to the use of PowerMock.  Personally, I find the need to use PowerMock a code smell.  Verify the public interface, not the private implementation.

Comment: @AndrewS, tried debugging, looks like the hello() method is getting called 3 times, but it is being done by mock, not sure why.. the util class this in debug had three values..
com.sd.demo.powermock.injectmock.UtilClass$MockitoMock$1924029473$auxiliary$SaGoJRDf@74ecacc3,
Mock for UtilClass, hashCode: 950729555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally make the test working, the solution is 'SPY'.. Spy on util class, so that not to tell which method to make real call. I am not sure how to inject spy, so used a setter..

@InjectMocks
    private ClassWithDependency classWithDependency;

```
private UtilClass mockUtil;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    UtilClass utilClass = new UtilClass();
    mockUtil = PowerMockito.spy(utilClass);
    classWithDependency.setUtilClass(mockUtil); 
}

@Test
public void testMock() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.when(mockUtil,"hi").thenReturn("Hi Java"); 
    final String msg = classWithDependency.welcome();
    final String msgExpected = "Hello World,Hi Java";
    logger.info("welcome method called:{}",msg);
    PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(mockUtil, Mockito.times(1)).invoke("hi");
    Mockito.verify(mockUtil, Mockito.times(1)).hello();
    Assert.assertTrue(msg.equals(msgExpected));
}
```